# Listen for bash command output and when matching a string, save to file and exit process

Tags: regex, bash, shell

My actual use case is with a docker image printing continuous output to STDOUT and never exiting.  I can replicate the same outcome using `ping`

Run `ping google.com`
When `icmp_seq=4` is matched (for example)
Then save matched string to a file
And `pkill ping`

I can match the string I need with:

```
ping google.com | grep -o "cmp_seq=4"
```

I can also write ALL of the output to a file:

```
ping google.com  &>> .env
```

I was expecting that this would work:

```
ping google.com | grep -o "cmp_seq=4" &>> .env
```

But with the above I get no output. So I also tried using `until`

```
until ping google.com | grep -o "cmp_seq=4"; do ; sleep 1; done;
```

Which outputs the string as expected, but then I cannot kill the process after:

```
until ping google.com | grep -o "cmp_seq=4"; do ; sleep 1; done; pkill ping
```

I am aware that I can set `-c4` to stop the output, but in my actual use case I am not using ping and am not able to stop the request in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` seems like the wrong tool. You can use regular expressions directly in `bash`:

```sh
ping google.com | while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ cmp_seq=4 ]]; then
       # Save the matched text and stop
       printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}" >> outputfile
       break
    fi
done
```

This will automatically kill the source command at the front of the pipeline, too, without having to use `pkill` or the like (Assuming it exits when it gets an error writing to standard output).

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer, answers the original question. My actual use case was with running a docker container, so just for reference and in case anyone else is doing the same with Docker, here is what I ended up with:

```
echo -n 'ENV_VAR_NAME=' >> .env
docker run --name="docker-instance-name" --network="host" --rm -it some/docker-image long-running-command | while read -r line
  do
    if [[ $line =~ keyprefix ]]; then
      docker stop docker-instance-name
      echo $line | grep -o 'keyprefix_[A-Za-z0-9]*' >> .env
    fi
  done
```

Noting that I couldn't use `break` but instead needed to run `docker stop` *before* attempting to output the line to a file.

`.env` results in:

```
ENV_VAR_NAME=keyprefix_abc123
```

Assuming the output of this command:

```
docker run --name="docker-instance-name" --network="host" --rm -it some/docker-image long-running-command

Some log
Some log
Here is your key: keyprefix_abc123 (Press ctrl+c to quit)
```

To be more specific, this was an issue that was occurring for me using the Stripe CLI. I wanted to get the signing key from the command output, see this GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/520)